# Accidentally click something in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Hi, I don't know what is this? is something like git? how do I redo it?

Comment: if you don't want SCM in this workspace delete the `.git` folder in the workspace root folder

Comment: Not sure what your question is but if you're asking what that view is, it's the (File) Explorer and you open/close it with Command+B (or Ctrl+B on Windows).

Comment: yes, I don't know what is the green icon for. I think it's I accidentally click git or something. Thus, I'm looking for a way to redo this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close visual studio code and open the folder where your project is located. In there you will find a folder called `.git`.

If you don't see the folder and you are on windows go ahead and click "View" at the top and make sure "Hidden items" is turned on.

[image: windows folder]

Go ahead and delete that folder and then open visual studio code again. You will notice you won't have those green text and icons anymore. I hope I helped!